# Meaning of notation: $x_{l,L}$

Tags: notation, rotations, fluid-dynamics

The question is show that $$x_{l,L}X_{L,k}=\delta _{kl}$$ but what does that notation even mean?? The topic of this is continuum mechanics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation uses the Einstein summation convention: sum over same indices.
The Kronecker delta $\delta_{kl}$ is the identity matrix.

This could be the component form of the matrix product of matrices $x=(x_{lm})$ and $X=(X_{jk})$:
$$
x X = I \Rightarrow \\
(x X)_{ik} = x_{lL} X_{Lk} = \delta_{kl} = \delta_{lk} = (I)_{lk}
$$

Comment: Also why does the LHS terms have commas on the subscripts and the kronecker delta one doesn't? (on the question i wrote)

Comment: So $x_{l,L}$ means a matrix with $l$ rows and $L$ columns right? and $X_{L,k}$ is matrix with $L$ rows and $k$ columns? But what values are actually in the matrix? or does that not matter...

Comment: how do I exactly prove the question though... I don't see how I can

Comment: @snowman I would need to have a look at the book or at least some context to answer why there are commas. This notation is used in tensor calculus and it might indicate that the quantity is indexed but not a tensor, e.g. a transformation matrix.

Comment: It is more likely that it is the component of the $l$-th row and the $L$-th column. $L$ seems to be the index of summation. I would normally expect lower case indices so there might be some other meaning attached. The only values which I can see are the 0 and 1 values of the Kronecker delta.

Comment: You could start to solve the problem by finding out the definition of small and big x.

Comment: In tensor calculus, comma's are often used to denote partial differentiation. I don't think this question can be answered absolutely without more context.